# Return a null from Function which returns a DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 public static DateTime ResolveDate()
 {
   return null;
 }
```

Im required to return a `null` value from a function which returns a `DateTime` Type .. My Main Objective is to NOT to use **MinValue** or return a `new Datetime();` [Which Returns a Default Date] and Frontend display the Date as a Empty Value (Blank) -> `""`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
public static DateTime? ResolveDate() 
{ 
    if ( someconditon = true )
    {
        return DateTime.Now
    }
    else
    {
        return null; 
    } 
}
```

An alternative is to use something like TryParse is working

```
Public static bool TryResolve (out Resolvedate)
{
    if ( someconditon = true ) 
    { 
        Resolvedate = DateTime.Now 
        return true;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return false;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: I want to return DateTime Too !

Comment: @Sudantha - Make up your mind. Do you want to return `null` or a `DateTime`? You can't return both.

Comment: You cannot have your cake and eat it too. See update: this allows a DateTime and a null. The disadvantage is that in the remainder of you code you have to test for null. But hey, you wanted a null

Comment: `if (notResolvable) 
  {
    return null;
  }  else{ return new DateTime();} ` Some this like this

Comment: It cant Error 25 `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'. `

Comment: Can i set a value to a `Nullable DateTime` ?

Comment: @Sudantha Don't use trial and error. That's hopeless. Read about nullable types. You must have a good C# book. If not buy one. But learn about things properly.

Answer (score 5):

Make it nullable

```
   public static DateTime? ResolveDate()
        {
            return null;
        }
```

You can then return null as you want and check accordingly

Have a read of this [Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can either return a `Nullable<DateTime>` like so:

```
public static DateTime? ResolveDate()
{
  if (notResolvable) 
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Which would be useable like so:

```
var date = ResolveDate();
if (date.HasValue) 
{
  // Use date.Value here
}
```

Or use the Try naming convention like so:

```
public static bool TryResolveDate(out DateTime date) 
{
  date = default(DateTime);
  if (notResolvable) 
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Which would be useable like so:

```
DateTime date;
if (TryResolveDate(out date)) 
{
  // Use date here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    bool somecondition = true;
    public DateTime? ResolveDate()
    {

        DateTime? date = null;
        if (somecondition == true)
        {
            date = DateTime.Now;
            return DateTime.Now;
        }
        else return date;
    }
```

Comment: I use nullable types fairly regularly when making calls to a database.